# requirejs module dependencies conflict

Tags: javascript, dependency-injection, dependencies, requirejs, amd

Module one:

```
(function (root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(['exports', 'my-lib'], factory);
    } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
        factory(exports, require('my-lib'));
    } else {
        factory((root.moduleOne = {}), root.myLib);
    }
}(this, function (exports, myLib) {
    exports.action = funciton(){};
}));
```

Second module:

```
(function (root, factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
        define(['exports', 'my.lib'], factory);
    } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
        factory(exports, require('my.lib'));
    } else {
        factory((root.secondModule = {}), root.myLib);
    }
}(this, function (exports, myLib) {
    exports.action = funciton(){};
}));
```

Problem in hardcoding "my.lib" and "my-lib" dependency.
When I include both to project I should:

- Modify source code of modules (change, for example, "my.lib" to "my-lib")
- or Declare both in my requirejs.config.path

Is there any better solution?

And second question:
When I create my own lib, maybe It will be better to do not hardcode module for define.amd, because there is no only one correct way to specify dependency name (unlike in npm modules).

Comment: Are "module one" and "second module" your own modules or modules produced that someone else that you want to use?

Comment: Both is third-party. In general for requirejs - I should specify one name for external module, but which name should I prefer? Not all packages are provided in npm, in bower many of libs have several names. For example for "knockout validation" in bower there are "ko.validation", "knockout-validation", "knockout.validation", "Knockout-Validation". And which name should I choose if two of them link to same git repo, but bower handle them separately. And when I added lib with bower, which name should I specify for requirejs path that will not conflicts in perspective?